# How to set options for chromium Edge() in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, microsoft-edge

I have been following tutorials, and I came up on Firefox, and using `Options()`, I could set headless mode while defining browser (`browser = Firefox(options=opts)`), but for **Firefox** only. I downloaded the driver for the new chromium Edge, but I cannot seem to set the `options=` keyword in `Edge()`. Can anyone tell me how do I set the options while defining the browser?

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Edge
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options

opts = Options()
opts.headless = True
browser = Edge(options=opts)
#              ^^^^^
```

It seems there is no options keyword, and I get an error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\tutorial.py", line 6, in <module>
    browser = Edge(options=opts)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'options'
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Edge Chromium you need to install msedge-selenium-tools package for python and then you can initialize the driver

```py
from msedge.selenium_tools import EdgeOptions

options = EdgeOptions()
options.use_chromium = True

driver = Edge(options)
```

Comment: Imports are missing. These is the required import: `from msedge.selenium_tools import EdgeOptions`

Comment: Does msedge-selenium-tools work with Python 3.9?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using Edge v118 and **selenium 4.14** (note that when trying to use msedge.selenium_tools, selenium was rolled back to a previous version, so I had to uninstall it and install it again). Similar to the examples shown in [Use WebDriver to automate Microsoft Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=python#automate-microsoft-edge), you can use the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options

import time # for demonstration purposes, not required


options = Options()
options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
# An example of option you can use:
# this is something I used to disable warning messages about not logging in.
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

driver = webdriver.Edge(options=options)

driver.get('https://ecosia.org/')

print("Entered website")
time.sleep(5)
print("Done waiting")

driver.quit()
```